# Pyside: QLineEdit taking multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, qlineedit

I have developed a GUI in Qt Designer in which user can enter two values in the `QLineEdit` and when the user hits enter it performs some mathematical calculations.

The issue is once the values are entered and enter is pressed after the output I am not able to type in inputs to the `QLineEdit` but have to restart the GUI every time. Here is my code:

```
    def entervalues(self):
        if self.RotationEdit.text() != "" and self.TiltEdit.text() != "":
            self.RotationEdit = str(self.RotationEdit.text())
            self.TiltEdit = str(self.TiltEdit.text())
            self.pass_arguments.emit("self.RotationEdit","self.TiltEdit")
        else:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error","No Values Entered")
```

If I try to enter values and hit enter it gives out Attribute Error.

```
    line 100, in entervalues
    if self.RotationEdit.text() != "" and self.TiltEdit.text() != "":
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

[image]

Comment: those values self.RotationEdit and self.TiltEdit are passed into another function which performs mathematical calculations when enter is pressed

Comment: its a QLineEdit

Comment: `self.pass_arguments.emit(self.RotationEdit.text(), self.TiltEdit.text())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises that in your code you are changing the object `self.RotationEdit`

```
self.RotationEdit = str(self.RotationEdit.text())
```

When you initially declare this is a QLineEdit, but then you assign a String. When you reuse it this will still be string so the `text()` function is not defined. I recommend creating a new variable that contains the values ​​that you will use in another function.

```
def entervalues(self):
    if self.RotationEdit.text() != "" and self.TiltEdit.text() != "":
        self.pass_arguments.emit(self.RotationEdit.text(),self.TiltEdit.text())
    else:
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Error","No Values Entered")
```